# Objects being created as DBO for all users in SQL Server application

Tags: sql-server, security, windows-authentication, user-management

We have Windows Authentication on our SQL Server Databases.

Every object gets created as `dbo` which I don't mind. But we are unable to track who created what? Can someone help on how it can be managed so we can at least track who is doing what? The login names from the trace is also generic

login name - ABC\gMSA_SQL$

If I login to the server with my windows authentication and run the below command select `SUSER_NAME()`, I can see my username and not a generic one. So now if I create a table where can I get this username from?

[image]

Comment: The schema is not what you want to use to track who creates stuff. That would be truly awful. You can use the default trace to view schema changes but that only goes back a little ways. Are you using source control for your databases?

Comment: If each user is supposed to be creating stuff that belongs to them and only they use, maybe each user should get their own database. Otherwise I agree with Sean - schema is not the way you track things. You can use [DDL triggers](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2085/sql-server-ddl-triggers-to-track-all-database-changes/?utm_source=AaronBertrand) going forward but as he suggests you're only going to get so much past information from [the default trace](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/48052/1186).

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thankyou. I am just trying to find a way to track as everything at the moment is very generic. I will definitely be putting in DDL triggers now but I have to confirm if I get the right username for it. There are multiple databases with a lot of data but atleast going forward we would have some sort of tracking on who is doing what. I dont mind getting any amount of history that I can get.

Comment: Hey @sean, we do not have a dba and I am more of a developer and the database is a mess. We cant track who created what as we have windows authentication enabled. If I use this command(select SUSER_NAME()) I am able to see my username. I wanted to find this username for object creation even if it doesnt go long back into history, I need to find it and start saving it in a user log table to track the DDL changes/updates. The login name that I can see is generic everywhere. Schema change history also has generic user name for every object. Anyone can create anything and everything on the server.

Comment: Here's an example implemention of DDL logging. Note it uses `SUSER_SNAME()` https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2085/sql-server-ddl-triggers-to-track-all-database-changes/ I can't tell from your comments if you currently have an issue with `SUSER_SNAME()` not being correct?

Comment: Of course this won't tell you anything about existing tables. If you want to check I like to use the "break and listen for screams" method: First create a "quarantine" schema: `CREATE SCHEMA bak` Now move objects into it and see if people complain: `ALTER SCHEMA bak TRANSFER <suspicioustable>`. If someone complains you can move it back. If no one complains leave it there and eventually delete it.

Answer (score 0):

The default schema of the user are set to `dbo`. It could be due to many reasons, as mentioned in the below [msdn reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-user-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

> The default schema will be the first schema that will be searched by
> the server when it resolves the names of objects for this database
> user. Unless otherwise specified, the default schema will be the owner
> of objects created by this database user.
>
> If the user has a default schema, that default schema will used. If
> the user does not have a default schema, but the user is a member of a
> group that has a default schema, the default schema of the group will
> be used. If the user does not have a default schema, and is a member
> of more than one group, the default schema for the user will be that
> of the Windows group with the lowest principal_id and an explicitly
> set default schema. (It is not possible to explicitly select one of
> the available default schemas as the preferred schema.) If no default
> schema can be determined for a user, the dbo schema will be used.
>
> DEFAULT_SCHEMA can be set before the schema that it points to is
> created.
>
> DEFAULT_SCHEMA cannot be specified when you are creating a user mapped
> to a certificate, or an asymmetric key.
>
> The value of DEFAULT_SCHEMA is ignored if the user is a member of the
> sysadmin fixed server role. All members of the sysadmin fixed server
> role have a default schema of dbo.

You can find out the default schema of the users by running the below query. [Refer to sys.database_principals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-database-principals-transact-sql?WT.mc_id=DP-MVP-7914&view=sql-server-ver15)

```sql
SELECT default_schema_name FROM sys.database_principals
```

If you want to restrict the users to only create objects on their schema, you have to do below things:

```sql
CREATE SCHEMA [userPrincipalSchema];
GO
CREATE USER [userPrincipal]
WITH PASSWORD='SUPERCOMPLEXPASSWORDHERE'  
    , DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[userPrincipalSchema]  
GO 
DENY ALTER ON SCHEMA::[dbo] to [userPrincipal]
GO
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::[userPrincipalSchema] to [userPrincipal];
GO
GRANT CREATE TABLE, CREATE VIEW, CREATE PROCEDURE TO [userPrincipal];
GO
```

This way, you can ensure that the [userPrincpal] is able to create objects only on their schema and you can track, the objects created by them.

Comment: Thankyou Venkataraman. I think I didnt make myself very clear. So I have edited the questiona lil. The problem is to find who created what on the server. Every one is using the same schema which is ok but every object is created by the same generic user. And I am unable to find what windows authentication username was used while creating a particular database/table/ any other object.

Comment: @Doodle, what permissions do these users have on the database ? are they have individual login or getting access through windows group ?

Comment: They have access through windows group as far as I can understand.  We login through windows authentication. and every login name is ABC\gMSA_SQL$
Every user can create any tables that they want

Comment: From the name it looks like, it is Managed Service Account and it could be used by application, which the users are using. All the users connect to application through windows authentication and in turn the application uses managed service account to connect to database. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/dd548356(v=ws.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN.